# Show that $F_N$ is closed in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and 
$$
F_N = \bigg\{f\in C[0,1] : \exists a\in [0,1] : \forall x\in[0,1], x\not = a \implies \bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\bigg|\leq N\bigg\}
$$

I want to show that $F_N$ is closed. I tried to use the limit characterisation, that is, if $f_n\to f$, then $F_N$ is closed iff $f\in C[0,1]$, but I do not know how to proceed. The main problem I found is that if you take a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $F_N$, then each $a$ of the definition is different for each $f_n$, and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://people.bath.ac.uk/mw2319/ma30252/sec-diff.html)